# SQL Server CE 4.0 - Counting frequency of distinct values in multiple columns

Tags: sql, count, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

I have a table with 20 columns and each row can have a value of 0-4 (integer) in each column.

I would like to count the number of 0's, the number of 1's, the number of 2's etc in each column for a given subset of the table which is specified in the where  clause.

A friend suggested `PARTITION`, but that's not supported in SQL Server CE. I suspect that I have to use `count(expression)` but I can't work out what the expression would be.

Can anyone give me a suggestion?

Thanks,
Will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**consider you have a table as below**
[image]

```
  Select min(subset.g), count(subset.val)
        from
        (
            Select 'c1 & '+cast(Val1 as varchar(4)) as G,
                            val1 as val
                from test
            Union all
                Select 'c2 & '+ cast(Val2 as varchar(4)) as G,
                       val2 as val
                from test   
            Union all
                Select 'c3 & '+ cast(Val3 as varchar(4)) as G,   
                   val3 as val
                from test   
        ) as subset
    Group by  Left(subset.g,2),subset.val
    Order by Left(subset.g,2)
```

**the the result set would be like this**

[image]

Comment: thats close, thanks, but I need those totals for each column, not just for the whole table.

Comment: @dontpanic Sorry for misunderstanding i just update my answer.

Comment: Those results look just like what I am looking for, however I'm getting an error on the keyword 'Left' in the group by clause. I haven't found reference to that word in the SQL Compact reference so I am wondering if its not supported. Thanks.

Comment: yes, Left is not supported, but I am going to try using substring instead.

Comment: ok please tell me if it helped and don't forget to check my solution as answer ;)

Comment: I think I may have translated your code to mine incorrectly because my results are different. I have tested it for 2 columns (of the 20) and my column names are atmresulttype1 and atmresulttype2. I have 4 rows with values 4,4,1,4 (same for both columns). When I run my code (below) I only get 2 rows returned : C1&1,2 and C2&4,6. those totals are correct, but I should get 4 rows returned with C1&1,1 and C1&4,3 and C2&1,1 and C2&4,3. I will post my code as an answer (I dont know how to add it in this comment)

Comment: you changed the group name length from 2 to 13
so you must change the second parameter of the left or
second parameter of substring function to 13

Comment: Select min(subset.g), count(subset.atmresulttype) from (Select 'c1&'+cast(atmresulttype1 as nvarchar(4)) as G, atmresulttype1 as atmresulttype from results Union all Select 'c2&'+ cast(atmresulttype2  as nvarchar(4)) as G, atmresulttype2 as atmresulttype from results) as subset Group by substring(subset.g,0,2),subset.atmresulttype Order by substring(subset.g,0,2)

Comment: oh...silly... I will try that. I thought the value '2' was referring to the string length of 'C1'

Comment: you must change the third parameter of substring function like this
substring(subset.g,0,13)

Comment: Great, that does work, thanks very much. Now all I have to do is go over the code and understand what it is doing!